# what order is the pole at 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

What order is the pole at $z=0$?

$$\int\frac{\sin(3z)-3\sin(z)}{\sin(z)(\sin(z)-3)} dz$$

And do I calculate this this way:

$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} f(z)$$

P.S.
I need to calculate residue at 0

Comment: Is $f$ any antiderivative of that other function?

Comment: ups, f is nothing, my bad... I deleted it.

Comment: Are you wanting to find the order of the pole $0$ (if it is indeed a pole) of any antiderivative of that rational $\sin$ function?

Comment: It should be a pole because it says so in the assignment :D at least I hope so. and its /0 so it should be a pole right? or not necessarily? :? I think the order is 2 but I'm wondering can it actually be 3?

Comment: A singularity need not be a pole. See [essential singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity). It can also be a [removable singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity). What exactly is the function whose pole order at $0$ you're trying to find?

Comment: Doesn't look like it has a pole at zero to me. The denominator of the integrand goes to zero like $z$. Numerator goes to zero like $z^3$. So the whole thing is well behaved as $z$ goes to zero.

Comment: That's the function which is being integrated in the question, involving trigs.

Comment: I actually need to calculate residue at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Write the denominator and numerator as a power series, and simplify things. Then, check the least exponent of $z$ in the denominator: that will be the order of the pole. If, however, the least exponent is $0$, the function has a removable singularity.

Comment: Yup thanks, it truly is removable singularity. So do I calculate the residue simply lim(z->0)(z-0)f(z)( ? Without any derivatives and factorials?

Comment: No, that would be if $0$ was a simple pole. If $0$ is a removable singularity, the residue is just zero.